# importing pandas causes pyodbc.connect to fail in python 3.11

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, odbc, pyodbc

When I import pandas into a script that uses pyodbc it causes the connection to fail.  isql works with this connection string

pandas==2.1.2
pyodbc==5.0.1

The database I'm trying to connect to is a local mysql database and I'm running this on ubuntu 22.04.

```
# This works
import pyodbc

db_connection = pyodbc.connect('connection string')
```

```
# This fails
import pandas
import pyodbc

db_connection = pyodbc.connect('connection string')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/test.py", line 4, in \<module\>
db_connection = pyodbc.connect('connection string')
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "\[01000\] \[unixODBC\]\[Driver Manager\]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc8w.so' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

This worked in python 3.10 using pyodbc==5.0.1, pandas==1.5.3 on ubuntu 20.04

Both machines are fresh VMs built with packer/vagrant and install python from the deadsnakes repository.

I tried downgrading pandas to an earlier version and switching the importer order also tried changing around the import order.

I tried switching to the python 3.10 in ubuntu 22.04 and that also failed  with the same message when importing pandas.

I also tried multiple different versions of the libmyodbc8 driver

Comment: By chance are you using Anaconda or a similar environment?

Comment: no it's a new ubuntu 22.04 VM with python installed from the deadsnakes repository

Comment: MySQL Connector/ODBC has had its share of problems over the years. If you are using pandas with MySQL then you should be using SQLAlchemy, and SQLAlchemy does not recommend using MySQL ODBC. Try using [PyMySQL](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.pymysql) instead.

Comment: I think I'm going to go with the PyMySQL option.  

It was mostly a drop in replacement for the pyodbc calls and avoids managing separate mysql drivers in the future.